# Convert interface type to a type that implements it fails?

Tags: c#

I have a class `Eater` that implements `IComparable` and `IComparable<Eater>`. Then I generate an array of type `IComparable[]`. Now because `Eater` implements `IComparable` I would think that the following conversion is valid:

`Eater[] = (Eater[])(new IComparable[] {1,2,3})`

However, this fails with `InvalidCastException` - why and how can I modify the code such that it becomes possible?

Comment: you can create an array of `IComparable[]` from an array of `Eater[]`, not vise versa. Cause for sure `Eater` has everything that `IComparable` need and `IComparable` not always has everything that `Eater` need (as it implements not only `IComparable`).

Comment: `Eater` will always be `IComparable`. But `IComparable` is not always `Eater`.

Comment: Perhaps relevant side note: You can cast an Eater array as an `IComparable[]` (as others have pointed out already) but that does not turn the Eater array into a true IComparable array. At its heart it is still an Eater array and even if you can cast it as an `IComparable[]`, it will not permit objects other than Eater's being placed into it...

Answer (score 2):

A cat is an animal. But not all animals are cats.

Or for you:

Eater is an IComparable. But not all classes that implement IComparable are Eater.

And what `new IComparable[] {1,2,3}` does is creating and Array of [Int32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32?view=netframework-4.7.2) (which is also implements IComparable. But Int32 is not an Eater.)

Something like this should work:

```
Eater[] = (Eater[])(new IComparable[] {new Eater(1),new Eater(2), new Eater(3)})
```

or

```
Eater[] = new Eater[] {new Eater(1),new Eater(2), new Eater(3)}
```

Comment: `new IComparable[] {1,2,3}` contains an array of `IComparable` references which point to boxed ints.

Answer (score -1):

If `Eater` implements `IComparable`, that means you can cast `Eater` to `IComparable`.

However, you are trying to do it the other way round, as you are casting `IComparable` to `Eater`.

You could do sth like `IComparable[] arr = new Eater[] { 1, 2, 3}`